# pseudo inverse of sparse matrix in python

Tags: python, linear-algebra, sparse-matrix, least-squares, matrix-inverse

I am working with data from neuroimaging and because of the large amount of data, I would like to use sparse matrices for my code (scipy.sparse.lil_matrix or csr_matrix).

In particular, I will need to compute the pseudo-inverse of my matrix to solve a least-square problem.
I have found the method sparse.lsqr, but it is not very efficient. Is there a method to compute the pseudo-inverse of Moore-Penrose (correspondent to pinv for normal matrices).

The size of my matrix A is about 600'000x2000 and in every row of the matrix I'll have from 0 up to 4 non zero values. The matrix A size is given by voxel x fiber bundle (white matter fiber tracts) and we are expecting maximum 4 tracts to cross in a voxel. In most of the white matter voxels we expect to have at least 1 tract, but I will say that around 20% of the lines could be zeros.

The vector b should not be sparse, actually b contains the measure for each voxel, which is in general not zero.

I would need to minimize the error, but there are also some conditions on the vector x. As I tried the model on smaller matrices, I never needed to constrain the system in order to satisfy these conditions (in general 0

Is that of any help? Is there a way to avoid taking the pseudo-inverse of A?

Thanks

**Update 1st June:**
thanks again for the help.
I can't really show you anything about my data, because the code in python give me some problems. However, in order to understand how I could choose a good k I've tried to create a testing function in Matlab.

The code is as follow:

```
F=zeros(100000,1000);

for k=1:150000
    p=rand(1);
    a=0;
    b=0;
    while a<=0 || b<=0
    a=random('Binomial',100000,p);
    b=random('Binomial',1000,p);
    end
    F(a,b)=rand(1);
end

solution=repmat([0.5,0.5,0.8,0.7,0.9,0.4,0.7,0.7,0.9,0.6],1,100);
size(solution)
solution=solution';
measure=F*solution;
%check=pinvF*measure;
k=250;
F=sparse(F);
[U,S,V]=svds(F,k);
s=svds(F,k);
plot(s)
max(max(U*S*V'-F))
for s=1:k
    if S(s,s)~=0
        S(s,s)=1/S(s,s);
    end
end

inv=V*S'*U';
inv*measure
max(inv*measure-solution)
```

Do you have any idea of what should be k compare to the size of F? I've taken 250 (over 1000) and the results are not satisfactory (the waiting time is acceptable, but not short).
Also now I can compare the results with the known solution, but how could one choose k in general?
I also attached the plot of the 250 single values that I get and their squares normalized. I don't know exactly how to better do a screeplot in matlab. I'm now proceeding with bigger k to see if suddently the value will be much smaller.

Thanks again,
Jennifer

[image: The image shows the 250 computed. I don't know exactly how to create a scree plot in Matlab.]
[image: squared normalized single values]

Comment: I don't know anything about the implementation of lsqr in sparse.linalg, but it seems unlikely that there would be a faster way to compute the pseudoinverse; if so, wouldn't lsqr just call that and then do the multiplication? EDIT: Or is the problem that you need to do many such calculations and want the pseudoinverse so you don't have to recalculate?

Answer (score 9):

You could study more on the alternatives offered in [scipy.sparse.linalg](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.linalg.html#module-scipy.sparse.linalg).

Anyway, please note that a pseudo-inverse of a sparse matrix is most likely to be a (very) dense one, so it's not really a fruitful avenue (in general) to follow, when solving sparse linear systems.

You may like to describe a slight more detailed manner your particular problem (`dot(A, x)= b+ e`). At least specify:

- 'typical' size of `A`
- 'typical' percentage of nonzero entries in `A`
- least-squares implies that `norm(e)` is minimized, but please indicate whether your main interest is on `x_hat` or on `b_hat`, where `e= b- b_hat` and `b_hat= dot(A, x_hat)`

**Update**: If you have some idea of the rank of `A` (and its much smaller than number of columns), you could try [total least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares) method. Here is a simple implementation, where `k` is the number of first singular values and vectors to use (i.e. 'effective' rank).

```
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from scipy.sparse.linalg import svds

def tls(A, b, k= 6):
    """A tls solution of Ax= b, for sparse A."""
    u, s, v= svds(hstack([A, b]), k)
    return v[-1, :-1]/ -v[-1, -1]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in both cases I don't understand how to deal with the fact that in SVDS k must be less than the rank.

Comment: @Jennifer: Firstly practical reasons dictate that k must be relative small, note that `u` and `v` are likely dense.

Comment: @Jennifer: Secondly there are some theoretical reasons, consider that `sum(s)`(of full `svd`) explains all the variations in `[A b]´, so you should find a `k` where `sum(s[:k])` would explain reasonable amount of the variations in `[A b]´ (consider this signal) and `sum(s[k:])` would explain the rest (consider this noise). You may like to study the linear algebra behind `svd` more detailed manner, but in practice you could plot `s[:k]` for some feasible k and if you are able to identify a change point there, use that as your `k`, for more details google `scree plot`.

Comment: @Jennifer: Can you show to us a `scree plot` for such `k` you are able to calculate in reasonable time? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Regardless of the answer to my comment, I would think you could accomplish this fairly easily using the [Moore-Penrose SVD representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Singular_value_decomposition_.28SVD.29). Find the SVD with scipy.sparse.linalg.svds, replace Sigma by its pseudoinverse, and then multiply V*Sigma_pi*U' to find the pseudoinverse of your original matrix.

Comment: @eat you're right, I flipped V and U. I think the rest is right, but I agree with your answer's point that the pseudoinverse is likely not the best way of solving her problem.